How to use require() in React
I'm new to React.
I was wondering how to read and write to JSON file and most people use require(fs) etc...
I know that require is not standard browser function (or Reacts) but I'm confused how to connect React with it?
I already have node modules in that folder and I thought that require function would be included in that (as when I worked with node.js)?
I thought that require would already be included since I have node_modules that came with react in that folder

require('fs') is commonly used in node.js to work with the file system.
However, in React which runs in the browser, you cannot use require('fs') because 'fs' is a node.js module, and the browser environment doesn't have access to the file system directly for security reasons.
React is a front-end library that runs in the browser, whereas 'fs' is part of Node.js, which is a server-side runtime. Browsers cannot interact with the file system directly like node.js can, so trying to use 'fs' in a React application will result in erros.
If you want to read data from a static json file in react, you can do so using 'import' or 'fetch.
-using 'import'
you can place the josn file in your 'public' directory or 'src directory and import it directly.
import data from './data.json'
function App( {
console.log(data);
return(
<div>
<h1> Data from json file</h1>
<pre>{JSON.stringfy(data, null, 2)}</pre>
</div>
);
}

export default App;


Using 'fetch'
you can also fetch the Json file if it's located in your 'public' directory.
function App() {
cosnt [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
React.useEffect(()=> {
  fetch('/data.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((jsonData) => setData(jsonData));
}, []};

return(
  <div>
    <h1> Data from json file</h1>
    <pre>{JSON.stringfy(data, null, 2)}</pre>
  </div>
  );

}
export default App;


